# JQuery show() and hide() on attribute has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div elements as below:

```
  <div class="sc-info" tags="abc mno">
     ....
  </div>

  <div class="sc-info" tags="abc xyz">
     ....
  </div>
```

I want perform hide() and show() based on value present in tags.Some thing like below

```
  $('div.sc-info[tags with "abc"]').hide()   // This should hide both divs

  $('div.sc-info[tags with "xyz"]').show()   //This should show only second one
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **Attribute Contains Word Selector** (`~=`) selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
$('div.sc-info[tags~="abc"]').hide()

$('div.sc-info[tags~="xyz"]').show()
```

---

**Response to comment:**

> Not working when I am checking for multiple word (i.e) str = "New York"; [str ~="abc New York"] is not giving correct results. Is there any other way to do it?

To select multiple words within those attributes you'll have to filter on `div.sc.info` for both possible attribute selectors.

```
$('div.sc-info').filter('[tags~="abc"],[tags~="New York"]').hide()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/AS6Zp/

Comment: Not working when I am checking for multiple word (i.e) str = "New York"; [str ~="abc New York"] is not giving correct results. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I am adding so many values dynamically for tags attributes of div.So I don't have control on values means it can have values like both New and New York. Then str with value New will return both divs (i.e) divs with New and New York but where I want only New. For this I did before adding values of tag I am replacing spaces of tag with two or more words with underscore so it can be treated as one. And same thing I am doing for str. By doing this I am getting correct results. If there is other way please let me know. Thanks for your reply :)